# Twilio iOS library non-functional on WiFi

Tags: twilio

I'm building an iOS7 app using the latest Twilio library. We have everything set up to make external calls and if I install the test app on an iPhone and disable WiFi I can successfully make calls. With WiFi enabled, and in the iOS simulator attempting to make a call results in a 30 second wait then a 31003 error code (timeout).

Are there other steps needed to make the library work on WiFi? Thanks!

Comment: Have you observed this same behavior on multiple devices? Multiple wifi networks? How about if WiFi is enabled but you're not connected to a network? Also try setting up a proxy like Charles. Also show your code.

Comment: multiple devices - yes, multiple wifi networks - not yet tested, wifi enabled and no cell network is the failing behavior, charles shows a connection to the capability token server but nothing apart from that initial call.